# Random sum of Random variable with floating numbers

Tags: random-variables, floating-point

Let $L$ and $S$ integer valued random variables $(0,1,2, \ldots).$
$R$ is another random variable which can be a floating numbers.

The RV $S$ is the least required number of $R$ to be equal or greater than $R$. Mathematically expressed as:

$$
\sum_{j = 1}^{S[m]-1} R[j] < L[m]  \leq   \sum_{j = 1}^{S[m]} R[j]
$$

Since $R$ is floating point, $U_m$ is defined to express the excessive part of $m$th block the inequality above is expressed as:

$$L[m] +U[m]  =  \sum_{j = 1}^{S[m]} R[j] + U[m-1] $$

For large number of $m$ the problem can be expressed as:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
L[1] + U[1] = {\mkern 1mu} U[0] + \sum_{j = 1}^{S[1]} R[j] \\
L[2] + U[2] = {\mkern 1mu} {U}[1] + \sum_{j = 1}^{S[2]} R[j] \\
L[3] + U[3] = {\mkern 1mu} {U}[2] + \sum_{j = 1}^{S[3]} R[j] \\
\qquad\vdots\\
L[m] + U[m] = {\mkern 1mu} U[m - 1] + \sum_{j = 1}^{S[m]} R[j]
\end{array}
$$
Note that $U[0] = 0$ at the initial state.

Are the following equations correct?

$$E[L] = {\mkern 1mu} E\left[ \sum_{j = 1}^S R[j] \right],\tag 1$$ and

$$E[L^2] = {\mkern 1mu} E\left[\left( \sum_{j = 1}^S R[j] \right)^2 \right] \tag 2$$

Note: I use law of large number and approximations to prove (1). But I am open to other suggestions for both (1) and (2).